# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
urllist = ['http://example.com',
           'http://example1.com']
i = 0
while i < len(urllist):
    source = urllib.urlopen(urllist[i]).read()
    regex = '(\d{3})/">(\w+\s-\s\w+)</a>'  # e.g. '435', 'Tom-Jerry' 
    p = re.compile(regex)
    db = re.findall(p, source)
    db = [tuple(filter(None, t)) for t in db]   

    hero_id = []
    for i in db:
        hero_id.append(i[0])

    i += 1
print hero_id
```

`db = [tuple(filter(None, t)) for t in db]`  `db` is a list of tuples like this: `[('564', 'Tom', 'Jerry'), ('321', 'X-man', 'Hulk')]`

The logic behind this should be the following: Start off with the `urllist[0]`, search for the regex, collect the `db`, for every tuple in `db`, take the `[0]` element from the tuple (the number) and append it to the `hero_id` list. While you're done, add 1 to `i` and repeat the whole process for the next url from `urllist` while there is none left.

When I run this code, I get this:

`i += 1
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple`

`i += 1` in the code is outside the for loop so this exception surprises me a little bit. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop `for i in db:` is changing the value of `i` inside the `while` loop. Use a different (more descriptive) name in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The "for i in db" loop assigns a tuple to i.  The scope of i is the function (or module, if this is module-scope code).

The only loop syntax in Python 2 that has its own scope is the generator expression.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Seemed simple but would never figured it out. This worked of course; There is second problem though. It appended (to the `hero_id` list) only numbers from the second url from `urllist` hmm... i guess `append` method first appended numbers from the first link and then ereased them and appended numbers from the 2nd url. Any ideas for different method maybe?

Comment: Items in the list did not get removed.  Rather, your loop creates a new, empty, list the second time through the loop.  That in itself does nothing to the first list you created, the first time through.  However, because the name "hero_id" is now bound to a different list, and no name is bound to the first list any longer, you can no longer get hold of the first list (and it will be garbage collected).  If you want the list to end up with all the ids in it, just move the hero_id = [] line out of the loop